# Detect click inside rectangle on image android

Tags: java, android

I have a image contains some rectangle.
I want to detect event when touch inside rectangle and how to get coordinates x & y of that.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Please see photo above :

[image]

Comment: There is a overridable method called `onTouchEvent`. This will have a parameter `Event` with it. This is where you can get your x and y position. Then you can use the `contain` method of the rectangle with these x and y positions. http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/

Comment: Thanks for your help  @R.Suntjens .
I had get x & y position over touch event , 
but i still have a problem is :  how to detect when i touch inside the rectangle with WHITE background .  
And how to get position of center of rectangle ?

Comment: If it is a static position, you can define a rectangle on the background to check on. If not, you should post more code, for us to help you.

Comment: If image is obtained dynamically, and you have no idea where that rectangle may be the only thing you can do is some image processing. You may want to use image binarization to split image into white/black part, then using some edge detecting mechanism determine (x,y) of your desired rectangle. However this is very heavy operation. It is hard to say anything if we don't know anything more about that image.

Comment: Thanks for help . 
I had updated photo. 
Currently i dont have any idea. I used FloodFill dectect pixels same color and it's white color & calculate step fill color , example : step > 40 , the click inside white area .
I think my problem need using opencv to resolve , but it very difficult , i have not used it ever .

Answer (score 1):

for getting an touch x and y coordinate you can override on Touch and than get the X and Y coordinate.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

    boolean handledHere = false;

    final int action = ev.getAction();

    final int evX = (int) ev.getX();
    final int evY = (int) ev.getY();

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            handledHere = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            try {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            defineArea(evX, evY);

            handledHere = true;
            break;

        default:
            handledHere = false;
    } // end switch

    return handledHere;
}
```

For getting the touch color

```
 int touchColor = getHotspotColor(R.id.image, evX, evY);
```

In getHotspotColor return the color of touch

```
public int getHotspotColor(int hotspotId, int x, int y) {
    if (imgHome == null) {
        if (IConstants.debug)
            Loger.d("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot image not found");
        return 0;
    } else {
        imgHome.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap hotspots = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgHome.getDrawingCache());
        if (hotspots == null || ((x < 1 || y < 1) || (x > hotspots.getWidth() || y > hotspots.getHeight()))) {
            if (IConstants.debug)
                Loger.d("ImageAreasActivity", "Hot spot bitmap was not created");
            return 0;
        } else {
            imgHome.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
            return hotspots.getPixel(x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

You get the touch color.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a clickable area and reject the clicks outside this zone :

**MainActivity** :

```
// Status Bar Height
final int statusBarId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
final int statusBarHeight = statusBarId > 0 ? this.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(statusBarId) : 0;

// OnTouchZone
final OnTouchZone onTouchZone = new OnTouchZone(100, 50, 350, 150);

// Image
final ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);
image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (onTouchZone.contains(event.getX(), event.getY() - statusBarHeight)) {
                    // Your action

                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

**OnTouchZone** :

```
public final class OnTouchZone {

    private final int left, top, right, bottom;

    public OnTouchZone(final int left, final int top, final int right, final int bottom) {
        this.left = left;
        this.top = top;
        this.right = right;
        this.bottom = bottom;
    }

    public final boolean contains(final int x, final int y) {
            return x > this.left && x < this.right && y > this.top && y < this.bottom;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for help @Denis.
But i don't have exactly touch zone area .
It just a same color area , example : white area like photo above .

Comment: @sheep, the problem with the color detection is this is a very heavy operation, and that will work with ALL the white pixels of your image, even those you do not want. Moreover, after a PNG or JPG compression, some group of white pixels become gray, so you'll need to set a tolerance too. It is difficult to advise you without knowing the image you want to use, but I have a golden rule that says "If the solution is complicated is that this is not the right solution." :)

Comment: Haha ... i like your golden rule :D @Denis
I will try some way to resolve it ;)